# How does caret resolve ties in the KNN classification?

Tags: r, classification, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

I have a multi-class classification problem, in which I'm using caret package k nearest neighbour classifier, (4 classes), which means that an odd number for k won't prevent classification ties.

So how does caret resolve ties in the k nearest neighbour classification?

Comment: In these cases, reading the relevant relevant help files is often the fastest  solution. Also, I am not sure that `caret` is doing the nearest neighbor match. It is usually a wrapper around functions in other packages.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [manual page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-84/topics/knn3) doesn't state it explicitly. But, a close inspection of the [source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/knn3.R#L265) reveals that it chooses the class randomly, via `sample` method in `R`. I've managed to reproduce the iris dataset example in the above linked man-page using `2` neighbours. It results in different class assignments under different runs (see the `75-th` test example).